# Tensorflow Lite: Cannot convert between a TensorFlowLite buffer and a ByteBuffer

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I have tried to migrate a custom model to Android platform. The tensorflow version is 1.12. I used the command line recommended shown as below:

```
tflite_convert \
  --output_file=test.tflite \
  --graph_def_file=./models/test_model.pb \
  --input_arrays=input_image \
  --output_arrays=generated_image
```

to convert .pb file into tflite format.

I have checked input tensor shape of my .pb file in tensorboard:

```
dtype
{"type":"DT_FLOAT"}
shape
{"shape":{"dim":[{"size":474},{"size":712},{"size":3}]}}
```

Then I deploy tflite file upon Android, and allocate input ByteBuffer that planed to feed the model as:

```
imgData = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
          4 * 1 * 712 * 474 * 3);
```

When I run the model on Android device the app crashed and then logcat prints like:

```
2019-03-04 10:31:46.822 17884-17884/android.example.com.tflitecamerademo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: android.example.com.tflitecamerademo, PID: 17884
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{android.example.com.tflitecamerademo/com.example.android.tflitecamerademo.CameraActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert between a TensorFlowLite buffer with 786432 bytes and a ByteBuffer with 4049856 bytes.
```

It's so weird since allocated ByteBuffer is exactly the product of 4 * 3 * 474 * 712 whereas tensorflow lite buffer is not the multiple of 474 or 712. I don't figure out why tflite model got a wrong shape.

Thanks in advance if anyone can give a solution.

Answer (score 3):

You could visualize the TFLite model to debug what buffer sizes are actually allocated to the input tensors.

TensorFlow Lite models can be visualized using the
[visualize.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/tools/visualize.py)
script.

If the input tensor's buffer size isn't what you expect it to be, then there might be a bug with the conversion (or with the arguments provided to `tflite_convert`)

Comment: I've solved though by tuning input and output tensor into same shape. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: how to use this visualize.py  script for the visualization of tflite model

Comment: @HarshGupta: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/faq#how_do_i_inspect_a_tflite_file

Answer (score 1):

**Hello guys**,
I also had the similar problem yesterday. I would like to mention solution which works for me.

Seems like TSLite only support exact square bitmap inputs
Like
Size 256* 256 detection working
Size 256* 255 detection not working throwing exception

**And max size which is supported**
257*257 should be max width and height for any bitmap input

Here is the sample code to crop and resize bitmap

```
private var MODEL_HEIGHT = 257
private var MODEL_WIDTH = 257
```

**Crop bitmap**

```
val croppedBitmap = cropBitmap(bitmap)
```

**Created scaled version of bitmap for model input**

```
val scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(croppedBitmap, MODEL_WIDTH, MODEL_HEIGHT, true)
```

https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/posenet/android/app/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/posenet/PosenetActivity.kt#L578

**Crop Bitmap to maintain aspect ratio of model input.**

```
private fun cropBitmap(bitmap: Bitmap): Bitmap {
val bitmapRatio = bitmap.height.toFloat() / bitmap.width
val modelInputRatio = MODEL_HEIGHT.toFloat() / MODEL_WIDTH
var croppedBitmap = bitmap

// Acceptable difference between the modelInputRatio and bitmapRatio to skip cropping.
val maxDifference = 1e-5

// Checks if the bitmap has similar aspect ratio as the required model input.
when {
  abs(modelInputRatio - bitmapRatio) < maxDifference -> return croppedBitmap
  modelInputRatio < bitmapRatio -> {
    // New image is taller so we are height constrained.
    val cropHeight = bitmap.height - (bitmap.width.toFloat() / modelInputRatio)
    croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
      bitmap,
      0,
      (cropHeight / 2).toInt(),
      bitmap.width,
      (bitmap.height - cropHeight).toInt()
    )
  }
  else -> {
    val cropWidth = bitmap.width - (bitmap.height.toFloat() * modelInputRatio)
    croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
      bitmap,
      (cropWidth / 2).toInt(),
      0,
      (bitmap.width - cropWidth).toInt(),
      bitmap.height
    )
  }
}
return croppedBitmap
}
```

https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/posenet/android/app/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/posenet/PosenetActivity.kt#L451
Thanks and Regards
Pankaj

Answer (score 0):

I had changed the image dimensions from the standard 224 earlier in the model creation process to 299 for other reasons, so I just searched my Android Studio project for `224` and updated the two `final` references in `ImageClassifier.java` to 299, and I was back in business.